# How to configure application which uses Autotools to build to external directory?

Tags: build, autotools

I've got application which uses Autotools (Autoconf, Automake etc) which builds object and binary files into project directory. It is not convenient, I'd like to have separate directory for them, e.g. "build" directory. I.e. I need "shadow build". Could anybody advise how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Autotools support out-of-source building by default, as described [in the Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html).  In a nutshell, you create a directory, anywhere, into which the build results should go.  You make that your working directory, and run the project's `configure` script from there:

```
mkdir ~/the_project-build
cd  ~/the_project-build
~/the_project-1.2.3/configure
make
make install
```

All built files should then go into the build tree you've created instead of into the source tree.  It is possible for the root of the build tree to be inside the project directory if you prefer.

Do be aware, however, that

1. This feature depends on Automake and Autoconf together.  Projects that use Autoconf without Automake require some manual attention to make out-of-source building work for them, and in my experience, such projects often don't receive that attention.
2. There is a number of things the maintainers of an Autotools-based project can do to break out-of-source building, so you cannot be fully confident that *every* Autotools project can be built this way straight out of the box.
3. On the other hand, Automake automatically provides a 'distcheck' target that tests out-of-source building, among other things, so package maintainers have a tool intended to help ensure that their projects do support out-of-source builds.  This improves the likelihood that any given project in fact does.

Comment: Successfully used suggested approach for several apps, but some failed. Failed apps require `autoreconf` call before `./configure` and such cases expect sources to be in build directory, at least if I call `autoreconf` without parameters. Could you suggest something for this case?