# How to shadow build nano?

Tags: build, autotools, nano

I need to build nano for several architectures so I need separate directories for object and binary files, i.e. I need "shadow build" or "out of source build". I've found `abs_builddir` variable in `Makefile.in` file, seems that it is what I need, but I could not find how to set it. Could anybody help with it?

UPD: Tried instructions from answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022952/how-to-configure-application-which-uses-autotools-to-build-to-external-directory), it required copying `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` to build dir to make `autoreconf` and `configure` and `automake` work, but then it wants me to copy many `*.in` files and then it wants me to copy sources which is bad solution, so I need another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure application which uses Autotools to build to external directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022952/how-to-configure-application-which-uses-autotools-to-build-to-external-directory)

Comment: `abs_builddir` is set by `configure`.  It is part of the support provided for out-of-source building, such as I addressed in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I've updated question.

Comment: Regarding your update: no.  `autoreconf` ordinarily should not be part of the build process.  It is only required or appropriate if you make changes to the *build system*, e.g. to `configure.ac` or one of the `Makefile.am` files.  In the event that you do make such changes, you run `autoreconf`, once, in the *source* directory.  You never need to manually copy anything to a build directory.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, @JohnBollinger. But what about `automake`? It also should not be part of build process?

Comment: The only one of the Autotools that participates in the build itself is `libtool`, if it is used at all, and that only only as invoked from `make`.  You don't need to run `automake` directly in any case, as `autoreconf` covers that for you.